# the best way to keep numpy array in order with new element added

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I am trying to add new elements to a sorted numpy array and keep its order (descending). What would be the best and the most efficient way? to keep the best n?

```
A = numpy.array ([[3,3,3,3],[3,3,2,2],[3,2,2,1]])
B = [[3,4,3,3],[3,3,1,1]] (or in numpy.array)
```

currently, my approach is firstly to concatenate A and B, then do the argsort and follow by [0:n]

The scenario is having n = 100K, size B can be as big as more than multiple 100Ks, the function would be rapidly called

Would anyone be able to hint some ways to improve this?

Thanks you

Comment: Please provide more details and the expected output

Comment: `np.searchsorted` may be useful. But keep in mind that growing an array, row by row, is expensive, making a whole new array at each step.

Comment: This is also what I am concerning about, how to reduce the timing for a growing array